# How to display different content when a user selects a radio button?

Tags: javascript

I want make one feature. HTML/PHP is no problem, but my JavaScript skill is really low. I know how to use it, but I don't know how to write such a thing. It should look [like this example.](http://www.wwe.com/superstars/therock)

Under the picture, there's something called a "MILESTONE" - but in this case, the action is `onhover`. I want to use the `onclick` event and a set of radio buttons. When the user clicks on one of the three radio buttons, the page will change the picture and the description, depending on which one was clicked - and without refreshing the page.

I don't really get how it works, but if each option were one single page and I could just include them all, it would be ideal.

Comment: I try to find something on the internet, but I don't really know, what I'm looking for and because of my low JavaScript skill, I really don't have much to try.

Comment: check my answer and the explanation.

Comment: You're either asking us to write this for you (if so, you're in the wrong place), or you're saying you don't have enough know-how (if so, you will need to go and read).

Comment: No, you don't understand me. I'm asking you for advice, the direction or something what help me with this. I know what I want, but I don't know how it's called -> what I must search for successfull finding, because I waste a lot of time and found nothing, so I came here for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is fairly broad, so I'm going to focus on the task of swapping visible content on a fired event.

Writing this in jQuery, but you should be able to translate it if you're not using JQ:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="picker" class="picker" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="picker" class="picker" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="picker" class="picker" value="3"/>

<ul class="content">
  <li><img src="foo1"/></li>
  <li><img src="foo2"/></li>
  <li><img src="foo3"/></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.content li { display: none; }
.content li.active { display: block; }
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.picker').on('click', function() {
  $('.content .active').removeClass('active');
  $('.content li').eq($(this).val() - 1).addClass('active');
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9SdvZ/1/

Comment: @TichomírDuchaplný - Glad to hear it! If this helped you, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Comment: yeah, but one more thing. The script works on the example link site, but not in my home and I can't figure out why.. I add a link to jQuery, but nothing happened..

Comment: @TichomírDuchaplný - I'm afraid I don't have enough info to answer that. Make sure you have a tag inside the page's `<head>` element like this: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`, and no JavaScript errors in the page. If you still can't get jQuery to work, you'll have to open another question about it or find a jQuery tutorial.

Comment: I figure out.. I copy and paste the script, just like was write in the example link and there was a missing part.. btw: thx again.. here the script which run correctly: $(window).load(function(){
    $('.picker').on('click', function() {
      $('.content .active').removeClass('active');
      $('.content li').eq($(this).val() - 1).addClass('active');
    });
});

Comment: It would also work if you put the code as-is in a `script` tag at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

If your skills are good enough in HTML & CSS then you will know how to style it properly. Here is a sample code I have just done that has the JavaScript (functionality).

Live example: http://embed.plnkr.co/xdpHX9FplgLgh9pN7lWZ/preview

**Explanation:**

You will have the following HTML markup:

```
<div id="controls">
  <input type="radio" name="slide" value="slide1.html"> 1
  <input type="radio" name="slide" value="slide2.html"> 2
  <input type="radio" name="slide" value="slide3.html"> 3
</div>
```

And you will have the following JavaScrit using jQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $('#controls').on('click', ':radio', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    $.get(target.val(), function(data) {
      $('#content').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Basically, the JavaScript (using jQuery) will do the following: after clicking a radio button the `<div id="controls" />`'s content will be replaced with the content of the file specified in the radio button value attribute.

Comment: I was just waiting for the OP to give me enough feedback to explain it. Is that the reason of the downvote?

Comment: I don't know about the other one, but that was the reason for mine. It's an easy fix, though; just include some working code and I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: sorry, I still don't get it.. I don't know nothing about jQuery, I heard about it, but never read about it. If I try it on my own, the page send me to slide(number).html, instead of display text and how am I supposed to make radio buttons from href example ?

Comment: @TichomírDuchaplný - You're going to have to learn those things on your own, I'm afraid. You'll need a foundation in JavaScript, HTML, and CSS to do this successfully.